# Files not visible to Jenkins running in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

I have created a very basic Dockerfile which wraps the official Jenkins Docker image. I am running an instance of my image and have come across the following problem:

I start and instance of my image and create a file in my instance in the /tmp directory(any directory will work) called tmp.txt.
I go to the "Script Console" of my running Jenkins instance and in the console, I type in the following code:

```
f = new File('/tmp/')
println f.list()
```

I expect to see a list of files including my newly created /tmp/tmp.txt but that file is not in the list. This is symbolic of the problem that is blocking me which is that I want to call evaluate() on a groovy script from a Jenkinsfile but that file is not script is not visible to Jenkins.

My gut feeling is that this has something to do with Docker file system layers. Something about the fact that since Jenkins is installed at a lower docker file system layer in the base image, it cannot access files created within the running instance layer above it. The behavior seems very weird but somewhat understandable. 
Has anyone encountered this issue before? If so, how were you able to resolve it?

```
FROM jenkins
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
USER root
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins 
RUN chown -R  jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash jenkadm
USER jenkadm
WORKDIR /home/jenkadm
COPY id_rsa /home/jenkadm/.ssh/
COPY id_rsa.pub /home/jenkadm/.ssh/
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/staples/ci-tools
RUN chown jenkadm:jenkadm /opt/staples/*
USER jenkins
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountMax=300 --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war"
```

Comment: Can you show us the Dockerfile?

Comment: I am going to do a test with just the base jenkins image to see if I can reproduce it to rule out any issues I might be introducing with my Dockerfile.

Comment: Maybe something to do with permissions? I see you're flipping between users there.